# Generate random value on new column, based on group value of other columns in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, random

We have following Dataframe:

```
------
G1|G2|
1 | 1|
1 | 1|
1 | 2|
2 | 1|
2 | 2|
2 | 3|
```

So based-on column `G1` and `G2` we have 5 groups: 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3.

I would like to create new column `isSelected` with following rule: **With N rows belonged to each group, I would like to randomize at least 50% rows will have value `1` and `0` for otherwise. Every group must have at least 1 row that `isSelected = 1` and [number of `1` rows] - [number of `0` rows] should be less than 1**

Following is one valid generation:

```
----------------
G1|G2|isSelected
1 | 1|1
1 | 1|0
1 | 2|1
2 | 1|1
2 | 2|1
2 | 3|1
```

Following is not valid:

```
----------------
G1|G2|isSelected
1 | 1|1
1 | 1|1 --> Not OK, this group has 2 1-row and 0 0-row.
1 | 2|1
2 | 1|1
2 | 2|1
2 | 3|0 --> Not OK, this group has 0 1-row.
```

How to do it directly in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Sequence can be assigned for each row in group with window function "row_number", and "sequence/2" remainder can be used for "isSelected" column:

```
val allColumnsWindow = Window.partitionBy("G1","G2").orderBy("G2")
df
  .withColumn("rn",row_number().over(allColumnsWindow))
  .withColumn("isSelected", $"rn" % 2)
  .drop("rn")
```

Comment: This ```random``` is not almost ```random``` lol but somehow it's very clear and good for me ! Thanks!